# Python, concatenation of two list

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, concatenation

I am new to python and I need to do this:

```
lines = ['apple','bear']
signed=['aelpp','aber']
```

I want the output to be:

```
res = ['aelpp apple', 'aber bear']
```

I'd appreciate if you can help! I've tried simply using + and the join() function but not getting what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and `join()`:

```
res = [" ".join(e) for e in zip(signed, lines)]
print res
```

**Output:**

```
['aelpp apple', 'aber bear']
```

**Edit**: As @ThiefMaster commented, this can be made more compact using `map()`:

```
res = map(' '.join, zip(signed, lines))
```

Comment: Could be done in an even more compact way: `map(' '.join, zip(signed, lines))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `zip`:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[1] + ' ' + x[0], zip(lines, signed)))
```

Comment: `map(lambda ...` is always better written as a list comprehension/generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to python, you may find the following easier to understand compared to the others:

```
>>> res = []
>>> for i in range(len(signed)):
...     res.append(signed[i] + ' ' + lines[i])
```

The results:

```
>>> print res
['aelpp apple', 'aber bear']
```